# How Do You Report Hackers On Tribes:Ascend?

Tags: tribes-ascend

There are a couple hackers on Tribes:Ascend.  How do I report them?  Do I report them to Steam or Viz Studios?  I got the game via Steam.

Comment: as far as I know, Tribes Ascend is no longer supported. Hi-Rez "finished" with the game years ago. It isn't even on Steam listing anymore https://store.steampowered.com/app/17080/Tribes_Ascend/ .

Comment: I know.  Was just hoping they'd respect the player and pay attention to the game

Comment: nope, Even Hi-Rez wants nothing to do with it, you cant find any mention of Tribes on their main site.

Comment: that just stinks. Thanks for looking.  Guess only answer is for an anti-hacker